# If $S\to C$ is surjective and $S$ is a rational surface, then $C\simeq \Bbb{P}^1$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, extension-field

Let all varieties be smooth, projective over an arbitrary algebraically closed field $k$.

Assume $f:S\to C$ is a surjective morphism from a rational surface $S$ to a curve $C$.

I've just read in Schütt & Shioda's *Mordell-Weil Lattices*, beginning of Section $7.1$, that in this case we have

"$C=\Bbb{P}^1$ and $K=k(\Bbb{P}^1)=k(t)$ is a rational function field. This follows, for instance, from Lüroth’s theorem stating that the only function field $k(C)$ contained in a purely transcendental extension of $k$ is a rational function field."

**Remark:** the authors assume $f:S\to C$ is a relatively minimal elliptic fibration, but I don't think this makes any difference for the argument above.

From what I could find about it, Lüroth's theorem for dimension 2 and arbitrary characteristic works only if $k(S)/k(C)$ is a separable extension (see [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/L%C3%BCroth_problem), for example).

What am I missing?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, the statement you have quoted is about the function field of the base curve, not the surface itself, so this is just ordinary Lüroth in dimension $1$.

Comment: @TabesBridges, to be more explicit, by Lüroth's theorem in dimension 1, if $L$ is a field, $t$ is transcendental over $L$ and $L\subsetneq L'\subsetneq L(t)$, then $L'=L(t')$ for some $t'\in L(t)$. I still can't see which are $L,t$ and $,L'$ in the quotation.

Comment: I just looked up the section you referenced, and now I think there could be a typo since, as you alluded to in your initial question, they seem to be trying to say something about $k(S)$ here but only make reference to $C$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It suffices to prove the following:

**Theorem.** Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $C$ an irreducible curve over $k$.
If there is a dominant morphism $f\colon U\to C$ from an open subset $U\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ of an affine space, then $C$ is rational.

**Proof.** Fix a closed point $x_0\in U$.
Since $f$ is dominant, there exists a closed point $x_1\in U$ such that $f(x_0)\neq f(x_1)$.
Consider the straight line $L\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ passing through $x_0$ and $x_1$.
Then $f|_{L\cap U}\colon L\cap U\to C$ is not constant and hence dominant.
Since $L\cap U$ is rational, Lüroth's theorem for **dimension 1** implies that $C$ is rational.

Comment: I really liked the geometric insight. This is excellent, thank you!